# How to extract the exact api call from failed stack

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I need to process the stack similar to below which has a string "oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.test.selenium.ApplcoreWebdriver" but I need the exact method call that failed. e.g. in this case the exact one is "oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.test.selenium.ApplcoreWebdriver.attachFile". There are multiple stacks that I have as part of html pages which I need to process and there will be multiple methods failing. How can I do it in shell script? This entire stack is in one line html entry which is causing grep to return the whole stack itself. I tried multiple things but nothing worked clearly. I guess awk or similar regex tool could be a way to go but not sure.

```
at oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test.selenium.RichWebDriverTest.getElement(RichWebDriverTest.java:1414)
at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.test.selenium.ApplcoreWebdriver.attachFile(ApplcoreWebdriver.java:1460)
at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.attachments.ui.util.accessor.FndManageAttachmentsPopupAccessor.attachFile(FndManageAttachmentsPopupAccessor.java:1475)
at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.attachments.ui.util.accessor.FndManageAttachmentsPopupAccessor.updateRowFileAttachment(FndManageAttachmentsPopupAccessor.java:550)
at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.attachments.ui.AttachmentsBaseSelenium.testLMultiFileAdd_22108390(AttachmentsBaseSelenium.java:1782)
at oracle.javatools.test.WebDriverRunner.run(WebDriverRunner.java:122)
```

Comment: So when you feed in `oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.test.selenium.ApplcoreWebdriver` you need to get `oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.test.selenium.ApplcoreWebdriver.attachFile` as the result, if I understand it right?

Comment: yes @lnian  thats what I want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot guarantee it being the most efficient of solutions, but am able so suit the need. Am using all `grep`, `sed` combined together.

Splitting the single big `html` file as multiple lines using `cat` & `tr`

```
cat file | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -w "$search_string" | sed 's/(.*)//'
```

For testing purposes am using the stack snippet which you shared in the OP.

```
$ cat file
at oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test.selenium.RichWebDriverTest.getElement(RichWebDriverTest.java:1414)
at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.test.selenium.ApplcoreWebdriver.attachFile(ApplcoreWebdriver.java:1460)
at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.attachments.ui.util.accessor.FndManageAttachmentsPopupAccessor.attachFile(FndManageAttachmentsPopupAccessor.java:1475)
at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.attachments.ui.util.accessor.FndManageAttachmentsPopupAccessor.updateRowFileAttachment(FndManageAttachmentsPopupAccessor.java:550)
at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.attachments.ui.AttachmentsBaseSelenium.testLMultiFileAdd_22108390(AttachmentsBaseSelenium.java:1782)
at oracle.javatools.test.WebDriverRunner.run(WebDriverRunner.java:122)
```

Running the above command for the search string `oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.test.selenium.ApplcoreWebdriver`

```
$ cat file | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -w "oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.test.selenium.ApplcoreWebdriver" | sed 's/(.*)//' 
oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.test.selenium.ApplcoreWebdriver.attachFile
```

Any suggestions simplifying it are welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts.. the problem is - this entire stack is in a single line rather than multiple lines as it looks. Hence the current o/p is printing incorrect results :-(

Comment: Since that line is in html format, new line is marked as <br/> tags.

Comment: @dganesh2002: Check out my updated answer with the handing added.

Comment: Thanks! This is even better as it avoids loops and can be done at the command line. There is one correction : grep -w "$search_string" file command is piped so doesn't need <file> as input

Comment: @dganesh2002 : Should have removed that during last edit. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found a working solution:

```
for stack in $all_stacks
do
        words=`echo $stack | tr ' ' '\n'`
        for word in $words
        do
                search_string="oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.test.selenium.ApplcoreWebdriver"
                if [[ $word == *${search_string}* ]];
                then
                        echo $word
                fi
        done
done
```

The idea was to split the line (stack) into words separated by space and process each word by matching with the required string. Then the matching word finally prints the required value (including api call)

**Update based on ans from @Inian :**

Below is updated one command to achieve this by processing multiple html files which contains error stack to be processed.

```
find . -name '*-errors.html' | xargs cat | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -w "oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.test.selenium.ApplcoreWebdriver" | sed 's/(.*)//' | cut -d '<' -f1 | sort -u
```